# Unix query --- finding the numbers

Tags: unix

On a Linux/Unix system, you have a directory full of files. You want to identify the files that have phone numbers in them, where you can assume a phone number looks like xxx-xxx-xxxx. Which standard Unix tools could you use to solve your problem?

I can use `egrep '[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+' *`

Is there any way I can use find command to solve this or any other commands to solve this ?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written? If you just want to get the filenames, and not see all the matching lines, use the `-l` option to `egrep`.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with `ls | egrep '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'`? you don't need `find` to serach a flat directory unless you want some complex postprocessing.

if you want to check the contents of files, use `egrep '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}' *`.

Comment: I think he's looking for phone numbers in the contents of the files, not the file names.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | perl -lne 'print if(/^[\d]{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/)'
```

Tested Below:

```
> touch 903-745-39913
> touch 903-745-3991
> ls -1 | perl -lne 'print if(/^[\d]{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/)'
903-745-3991
>
```

Your question is not quite clear.If you mean phone numbers are present inside the file.
Then,

```
ls| xargs perl -lne 'print if(/\b[\d]{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b/)'
```

will server the purpose.

Comment: If I understand the question right the phone numbers are in the file content - not in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sed

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/p' phonelist.txt
```